# jquery datatable disable sort in specific row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How to disable sorting in specific row/column in jquery datatable using a class?

here's my sample table;

```
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="sorting_disabled">Title1</th>
    <th class="">Title2</th>
    <th class="sorting_disabled">Title3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Tag 1</td><td>Date 1</td><td>Date 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tag 2</td><td>Date 2</td><td>Date 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tag 3</td><td>Date 3</td><td>Date 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tag 4</td><td>Date 4</td><td>Date 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tag 5</td><td>Date 5</td><td>Date 5</td></tr>
....
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

script;

```
$('.sortable thead tr th.sorting_disabled').livequery(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('sorting');
       $(this).unbind('click');
    });
```

above code works but if I click to the next column who has a sorting its shows again an arrow. though its not clickable ;(

How can I disable the sorting by using a class and not using/redraw a table.

Comment: what is meant by sorting here??

Comment: above code is just a sample table :) Ive edit it already..

Comment: You can set `bSortable` to false for those columns, in `aoColumns` def. Check this example, sorting is disabled on first and second column http://live.datatables.net/awizop/edit#preview

Comment: I know Sir, but the given code always set in the first column though we can set it by its script. below answer may used as a dynamic code for a class who has a 'sorting_disabled'.

Answer (score 11):

You can disable the sorting using a class in  definition.
Just add this code to the datatable initialization:

```
// Disable sorting on the sorting_disabled class
"aoColumnDefs" : [ {
    "bSortable" : false,
    "aTargets" : [ "sorting_disabled" ]
} ]
```

Answer (score 4):

The only solution:
First add `class="sorting_disabled"` to any`<th>` that you want to disable sorting, then add this code to the datatable initialization:

```
        // Disable sorting on the sorting_disabled class
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
            "bSortable" : false,
            "aTargets" : [ "sorting_disabled" ]
        } ],
        "order": [
            [1, 'asc']
        ],
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution for jq dataTables to disable sorting any specific target

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "aoColumnDefs": [
      { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1 ] }
   ]});
```

That should do it..;)

Answer (score 2):

try the following answer .it works for me.

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="tmp">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>Total Visitors</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Javascript</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PHP</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HTML5</td>
        <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CSS</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XML</td>
        <td>54</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="no-sort">
        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td><strong>118</strong></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

source : http://blog.adrianlawley.com/tablesorter-jquery-how-to-exclude-rows

Answer (score 2):

```
<th class="sorting_disabled">&nbsp;</th>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourDataTableDivID').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [
           {
               "bSortable": false,
               "aTargets": ["sorting_disabled"]
           }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in the [Datatables documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html):

> As of DataTables 1.10.5 it is now possible to define initialisation options using HTML5 data-* attributes. The attribute names are read by DataTables and used, potentially in combination with, the standard Javascript initialisation options (with the data-* attributes taking priority).

Example:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th data-orderable="false">Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I strongly recommend using this approach, as it is more cleaner than others. DataTables 1.10.15 was originally released on 18th April, 2017.

Comment: I tried few suggestions, only this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code works in your case.

```
        $("#dataTable").dataTable({
            "aoColumns": [{"bSortable": false}, null,{"bSortable": false}]
        });
```

You need to disable sorting via "bSortable" for that specific column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bSortable": false },
            null,
            { "bSortable": false }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came with almost the same solution like in the question, but I used the "fnHeaderCallback". As far as I understood, it gets called after each header redisplay, so no more worries about 'sorting' class that appears again after clicking on column next to target column.

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
  "fnHeaderCallback": function() {
    return $('th.sorting.sorting_disabled').removeClass("sorting").unbind("click");
  }
});
```

Additional documentation about callbacks: http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me in react.

in row created i added fixed-row class to the row i wanted to stay fixed and not sortable and i drawcallback i hid the row then i appended it to the table itself.

Hope this works for you:

```
$(this.refs.main).DataTable({
        dom: '<"data-table-wrapper"t>',
        data: data,
        language: {
            "emptyTable": "Loading ...",

        },
        columns,
        ordering: true,
        order: [0,'asc'],
        destory:true,
        bFilter: true,
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true
        },
        iDisplayLength: 100,
        scrollY: '79vh',
        ScrollX: '100%',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            var dataTableId = $("#To_Scroll_List").find(".dataTables_scrollBody table").attr("id");
            $("..fixed-row").css('display','none');
            $("#"+dataTableId+"_wrapper table").find('tbody tr:last').after($('.fixed-row'));
            $(".fixed-row").show();
        },
        createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
                if(data.UnitsPerLine == 999){
                    $(row).addClass('fixed-row');
                } 
        },
        initComplete: function (settings, json) {

           $("#To_Scroll_List").find(".dataTables_scrollBodytable").attr("id");
            $("#"+dataTableId+" thead tr").remove();



            });

            DatatableSearch(dataTableId+"_wrapper table", "AverageUnitsPerLineReport");
        }     
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using class, you can follow these steps:

1. Remove the row which has to remain unsorted from the body of the table.
2. Include the row to be added in the footer of the table if it is the last row.

Answer (score 0):

I did it including the code below in drawCallback:

```
drawCallback: function(settings) {
    let td = $("td:contains('TOTAL')");
    if (td.length) {
        let row = td.closest('tr');
        let clonedRow = row.clone();
        row.remove();
        $('table tbody').append(clonedRow);
    }
}
```