# Datatables orderable=false directly on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have several tables, I want to create a single javascript file to manage them
The problem is they do not have the same number of columns.

So I can not put :

```
"columnDefs": [{ "targets": [ 3, 4 ], "orderable": false }]
```

because the first table has only 3 columns
so I would have disabled the ability to sort directly on the table like :

```
<th data-sort"false"></th>
```

It's possible ? How I can do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need the data attribute `data-orderable` instead.

```
<th data-orderable="false"></th>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me maybe because I'm using an archaic version of DataTables.  [This answer from "jquery datatable disable sort in specific row"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17157821/) worked though.